# how i can call the matchmedia function without changing browser dimensions

Tags: javascript, responsive, matchmedia

i'm not very good in javascript, but i tried this function.

```
<script> 

function myFunction(divswitch) {
  if (divswitch.matches) { // If media query matches

  } else {

  }
}

var divswitch = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 640px)")
myFunction(divswitch) // Call listener function 
divswitch.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener 


</script>
```

The Script only called if the user switch their browser dimensions. 
could someone fix the code for users, which doenst switch their browser dimensions. its for screens smaller than 640 px like mobile phones.

Comment: You should addListener to some event, for example `resize`, or `load`
your divswritch variable is not an event.

Comment: dont know how;
I tried; this codes:

divswitch.addEventListener("load", myFunction);
or window.onload = myFunction(divswitch)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```js
function logMatchStatus(divswitch) {
  if (divswitch.matches) { 
    console.log("It matches");
  } else {
    console.log("It doesn't");
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var divswitchExample = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 640px)");
    logMatchStatus(divswitchExample);
})
```

I changed some names to be more meaningful(and I encourage you to do that always) but kept your code same.

You can read about addEventListener [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Also note, that in my example I use `resize` event, so you can run snippet, check console and change window width to ensure it works. If you need your function to fire only on page load replace `'resize'` with `'load'`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's important, that the script runs on pageload and on resizing.
That's Why i write this Script.

```
function mobilefix(divswitch) {
  if (divswitch.matches) { // If media query matches
    $("#divid").insertAfter("#otherdivid")
  } else {
    $("#otherdivid").insertAfter("#divid")
  }
}  

var divswitch = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 640px)");
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    mobilefix(divswitch);
})
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    mobilefix(divswitch);
})
```

thx @vicodin

The code is a bit long. But the result is as expected.

The only question is how to change 2 divs on the basis of the media size even shorter. But not so important.